# Is it possible to type hint exclusively a class object but exclude subclass objects?

Tags: python, python-3.x, type-hinting

I would like to exclusively type hint an argument to a specific class but exclude any subclasses.

```py
class A:
    pass
class B(A):
    pass

def foo(obj: A):
    pass

foo(B()) # I'd like the type checker to warn me here that it expects A, not B
```

Is this possible? and if so, how?

*(bonus points if you can tell me what I would call this.  Googling wasn't helpful, but I'm afraid I'm using the wrong terminology to describe this)*

Comment: This seems like poor OO design. Anything that accepts a class should also accept any of its subclasses.

Comment: And I don't know of a way to achieve this. It wasn't included in type hinting, probably for the reasons above. Maybe make `A` and `B` separate subclass of a common base class?

Comment: Use `mypy`, it exclusively tells what types need to be hinted.You could use mypy from command line, there is pycharm plugin available for it too.

Comment: There are occasionally legitimate reasons to do this, such as when a function is specifically an optimized code path that assumes no methods have been overridden, but Python's type hint system offers no support for it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, this is not possible to do.

Fundamentally, the Python typing ecosystem assumes that you are following the [Liskov substitution principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle) -- assumes that it is always safe to substitute a subclass in places designed to handle the parent.

The fact that it permits you to pass in instances of B in addition to instances of A in your code snippet is just one example of this principle in play.

So if your subclass B is designed *not* to follow the Liskov substitution principle, that probably it wasn't ever really a "kind of" A to begin with and shouldn't be subclassing it.

You could fix this by either adjusting your code so B does properly follow Liskov or by making B stop subclassing A and instead use composition instead of inheritance as a mechanism for code reuse. That is, make B keep an instance of A as a field and use it as appropriate.

And if you run into a rare case where it's legitimately not possible to ever subclass A without breaking Liskov, something you could do to prevent people from accidentally subclassing it would be to explicitly mark A as being [final](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0591/):

```py
from typing import final
# If you want to support Python 3.7 or earlier, pip-install 'typing_extensions'
# and do 'from typing_extensions import final' instead

@final
class A: pass

class B(A): pass
```

This should make your type checker report a "B cannot subclass A" error on the definition of B. And if you fix that error by changing/deleting `B`, the call to `foo(B())` should also naturally fail to type-check.

Answer (score 1):

The terms you're looking for are covariance and contravariance

> Variance refers to places where one data type can be substituted for another.
>
> - Covariance means that a data type can be substituted with a more specific type
> - Contravariance means that a data type can be substituted with a more general type
> - Invariance means that a data type cannot be substituted either way

*from https://www.playfulpython.com/type-hinting-covariance-contra-variance/*

I would say you're trying to type hint a function parameter as invariant.

By default, normal types in Python are assumed to be covariant (i.e. any where you can use `A` you can also use `B`).
However [PEP-484](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/#covariance-and-contravariance) states:

> By default generic types are considered invariant in all type variables, which means that values for variables annotated with types like List[Employee] must exactly match the type annotation -- no subclasses or superclasses of the type parameter (in this example Employee) are allowed.

Extending OPs code to demonstrate a bug that can occur with a List:

```py
class A:
    pass


class B(A):
    def do_something_b_specific() -> None:
       pass

def add_an_a(a_list: List[A]) -> None:
    a_list.append(A())

b_list: List[B] = [B(), B()]
add_an_a(b_list)  # Now our List[B] actually contains an A!

for b in in b_list:
    b.do_something_b_specific()  # This will cause an error because the A instance doesn't have this method!
```

Obviously, python doesn't prevent you from doing this, and from a type hinting point of view, this is all correct because Lists are considered not to be covariant, so it's our own fault for passing a List of Bs into something that expects a List of As.

In terms of type hinting your `foo` function,  a solution may look like this (I haven't checked this with mypy, so I'm not 100% that it's correct)

```py
from typing import TypeVar

A_nonco = TypeVar("A_nonco", bound=A, covariant=False)  # covariant=False is actually the default, but making it explicit for the sake of the answer

def foo(obj: A_nonco):
    pass
```